# How to define my own loss function in Keras?

Tags: keras, lstm, python-3.5

I am trying using CuDNNLSTM in Keras to deal with some sequential questions with multiple outputs. My code is written as follows:

```
inputs = Input(...)
lstm_outputs = CuDNNLSTM(n_neurons, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
outputs = TimeDistributed(Dense(3))(lstm_outputs)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

When I using the mean_square_error as loss function in Keras, the results seem like

> error = np.mean(np.square(y_pred - y_real))

where the feature number of y_pred and y_real is 3.

But I want to define the loss function as following:

> error = np.mean(np.square(y_pred[:, :, 0] - y_real[:, :, 0]) +
>   np.square(y_pred[:, :, 1] - y_real[:, :, 1]) + np.square(y_pred[:, :,
>   2] - y_real[:, :, 2]))

I don't know how to implement this, can anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the difference? Your second loss is just your first loss times 3, isn't it?

Comment: Of course, it is different. The first will calculate the square of the sum of three errors, but the second will calculate the sum of the square of three errors. @Yu-Yang

Comment: No. The first will compute the element-wise errors, element-wise square, and then finally average all the elements. There's no `sum` in your first loss.